# Exp:resso Store - Add Shipping Cost after checkout

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

I'm currently in the midst of a Store development for a wholesale site that cannot use automated shipping due to the nature of the product (jewels / gem stones).

The client has to manually work out the shipping cost after the purchase order has been placed.

Is there a way to edit the order / add shipping after the end user has placed their order? This is so that the shipping / insurance costs can be manually calculated and then added to the invoice retrospectively.

There is no payment gateway on this site - it's 30 day invoicing to payment gateway is set to manual.

Thanks,

Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this from the control panel, and even the developer API doesn't have an easy way to recalculate/edit an order after it has been placed.

The best way to approach this would be to write a custom module which provides an interface where your client can update the shipping cost of an order. When you save this back to the database, be sure to update the order tax & total as well if they have changed.

At this point it should be fairly easy for you to send an invoice link back to the customer where they can pay by credit card (or manually record payments if they are paying via bank transfer).

Comment: Module is in active development - will release shortly.